# Xcode: Preview Image Tint Color In Interface Builder

Tags: xcode

I'm hoping to preview the tint color of my images in the Interface Builder (for designers' sakes) but have had no luck. I tried setting the image asset rendering mode to Template & then selecting a tint in Interface Builder, with no luck. Is there any way to do this? If code is required, please provide an answer with Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the downvote with no feedback. Very helpful.

Comment: waw... i voted this post up 2 years ago i think, and now i tried again to upvoted it... lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite no help from downvoters, I found a partial answer. I subclassed my image view like this -

```
@IBDesignable
class TintPreviewableImage: UIImageView {

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        self.image = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
}
```

Then I added the `TintPreviewableImage` class to the UIImageView in the identity inspector. Now I see a live preview after selecting a tint color in the Interface Builder. The only problem is the icon is blurry if the image view is bigger than the native size - I'm still trying to get Xcode to redraw the PDF vector image.